# SceneKit, call a function from Overlay scene

Tags: objective-c, swift, overlay, instance, scenekit

I can take answers in either Swift or Objective-C.

I'm using SceneKit, and I have a 2D `OverlayScene` that's displaying on top of the 3D `GameScene`. I'd like `GameScene` to be able to reference back and forth between `OverlayScene` so that I can detect taps, run functions, etc. But whenever I try to create an instance of `Overlay`, I get various crashes. I have tried a few things, including but not limited to:

```
/* THIS IS IS MY 3D GAME-SCENE */

// Some crash about not using "init(size:CGSize)".
let overlayScene = SK_OverlayScene()

// There is no such thing as "self.size" in SceneKit.
let overlayScene = SK_OverlayScene(size: self.size)

// Some crazy crash I can't figure out at all.
let overlayScene = SK_OverlayScene(size: myGameViewController.sceneView.bounds.size)
```

In other words, I have tried many different solutions. If you don't believe that I did one of those solutions correctly, then ask me for the exact code and I'll give it to you.

My question is this: am I even going about this the correct way? Should I be using instances of the overlay scene, or should I be trying to contact the scene directly? I'm not really sure what's wrong here, that's why I'm asking for help.

***EDIT: I have already tried to move the code inside `OverlayScene`'s `init(size:CGSize)` into a simple `init()`, but that is also giving me problems.***

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking since we don't know what `self` is and how `SK_OverlayScene` is defined

Comment: SK_OverlayScene is an SKNode.

Comment: and `self`? If it hasn't a size you might think it's an `SCNView` where in reality it's a view controller. Also verify that your size in not `CGRectZero`.